# DecimalFormat change . by ,

Tags: android, string, format

I use this code to try to format a Double to String in Android:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("USD ###,###,##0.00");

String result = decimalFormat.format(87359.0);
```

I'm looking for "USD 87,359.00" but I get "USD 87.359,00" in some devices.

Any idea?

Comment: That is because the `DecimalFormat`uses the `locale` of the users device.

Answer (score 0):

`DecimalFormat` is localizable. If you do not specify a `Locale` then `DecimalFormat` uses the `Locale` the user has set on their device.

If for some reason you wish to override the `Locale` the user has set for his device then you can do something like this:

```
private String formatMyCurrency(double d){
    String result = "";
    try{
        String pattern = "USD ###,###,##0.00";
        //Use which ever locale you need
        //If you would rather have $ instead of USD you can use NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US) and adjust your pattern
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
        df.applyPattern(pattern);

        result = df.format(d);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or you could do this (**But, I don't recommend it!**):

```
private String formatMyCurrency(double d){
    String result = "";
    try{
        String pattern = "USD ###,###,##0.00";
        String sep = ".,";
        DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        dfs.setDecimalSeparator(sep.charAt(0));
        dfs.setGroupingSeparator(sep.charAt(1));
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(pattern, dfs);

        result = df.format(d);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Disclaimer**

The code above was written in a standard text editor-so some of the Method names may be incorrect or a syntax error may be in the code somewhere